# Convert a Command line tool to a .app in xcode

Tags: c++, c, xcode

So I just started c/c++ coding, and I was making a command line tool with .c and .h files that outputs text to the screen. What I was wondering is if there was any way to convert it to an executable file that a user can download and run without having to compile or manually launch from terminal. Otherwise, they will have to download a .c and a .h file, and compile it in their terminal.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want them to run it in Xcode?

Comment: @CarlNorum I want it to run in their terminal

Comment: So why does your question say you want them to run it in Xcode?

Comment: @CarlNorum sorry, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to 'convert' anything.  An executable is already part of the build results from your Xcode project.  Right click the exectuable product in the Xcode window and pick "show in Finder", and there it is.

If your users aren't comfortable with the command line, simply double-clicking the executable in finder will launch a terminal and run the program.

Comment: Sorry, but where do I find the executable product?

Comment: In a test project I just made, it's in the left sidebar under 'Products', and named the same as the project.